# JQuery: add click event to all children, doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add an "active" class to one and only one clicked menu item at a time. The active class then allows me to turn the background of the selected menu item to green.

When I added the .click() to each children individually, it works, but not with the current .children().each(), etc.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

```js
    $("#left_menu").children().each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        $(this).siblings().each(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }



        });
    });
    });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #e9ebee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e9ebee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000; 
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="left_menu">

        <li><a id="tab_wireless" href="#">System Status</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab_system" href="#">Network Configuration</a></li>

  <li><a id="radio_list" href="#">Radio List</a></li>
  <li><a id="search" href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Problem with your code is you are `adding class` on `children of ul` i.e. `li`. while in `css` below `active` class on `a`

```
li a.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}
```

If you will change active class from `a` to `li` then your current code will also work.

```
li.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}
```

**Here is code snippet of your current code:**

```js
$("#left_menu").children().each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if (!$(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        $(this).siblings().each(function(){
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            }



        });
    });
    });
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #e9ebee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e9ebee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000; 
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="left_menu">

        <li><a id="tab_wireless" href="#">System Status</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab_system" href="#">Network Configuration</a></li>

  <li><a id="radio_list" href="#">Radio List</a></li>
  <li><a id="search" href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

**2.** Better way you can do this on **`$('ul li a').click`**

**Here is code snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
     $('li a').removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #e9ebee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #e9ebee;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000; 
    padding: 8px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
    background-color: #008b10;
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="left_menu">

        <li><a id="tab_wireless" href="#">System Status</a></li>
        <li><a id="tab_system" href="#">Network Configuration</a></li>

  <li><a id="radio_list" href="#">Radio List</a></li>
  <li><a id="search" href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

You really dont need so many event handlers. you could just do this with a couple of lines of code using delegates and making use of event bubbling.

Here is the code sample.

```js
$("#left_menu").on('click', function(event) {
  $("#left_menu a.active").removeClass("active");
  $(event.target).addClass('active')
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #e9ebee;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid #e9ebee;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a.active {
  background-color: #008b10;
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="left_menu">

  <li><a id="tab_wireless" href="#">System Status</a></li>
  <li><a id="tab_system" href="#">Network Configuration</a></li>

  <li><a id="radio_list" href="#">Radio List</a></li>
  <li><a id="search" href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check with the following code. Here on clicking other li element's 'active' class is removed and the 'active' class is added on the clicked item.

```
$("#left_menu li").click(function(){
  var clicked_li = $(this);
  $("#left_menu li").not(clicked_li).removeClass('active'); // Will remove the class active if it is present;
  clicked_li.addClass('active'); // Will add the class if does not exists;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the color to change, then you have to apply the changes to the `a` tag not `li`. So I have solved the issue using the following jQuery and I have also optimized your code:

```
$(this).click(function(){
        $("li a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zfa0p45b/13/) is the link to the jsfiddle, I havent changed a bit in your HTML or CSS, all I have done is, change you css.